# XSLT using choose for existence of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to check if a node exists using "choose" and then extract the text within it. If not a string should be inserted.
here is what I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0"
xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"
xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<!-- identity templates walks tree and suppresses nodes with no template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- output only on nodes we select -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="output">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="output"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="gmd:pointOfContact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty">
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="gmd:individualName/gco:CharacterString">    
               <xsl:text>Responsible: </xsl:text>
               <xsl:apply-templates mode="output"/>
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NO Responsible: ;</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In this example the entire node to be searched is: "gmd:pointOfContact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty/gmd:individualName/gco:CharacterString"

my output should be a txt file like the following line:

*Responsible: Pippo;*

when the node exists and the string is "Pippo".

*NO responsible: ;*

when the node does not exists.

Could you please tell me why I'm not able to get this result?

here is an extracted part of an xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmi:MI_Metadata xmlns:gmi="http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" gco:isoType="gmd:MD_Metadata" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi http://sdi.eurac.edu/metadata/iso19139-2/schema/gmi/gmi.xsd">
<gmd:pointOfContact>
                <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
                    <gmd:individualName>
                        <gco:CharacterString>Pippo</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:individualName>
                </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
</gmd:pointOfContact>
</gmi:MI_Metadata>
```

in certain case it could happen that I can find somthing like this:

```
<gmd:pointOfContact>
                <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
                    <gmd:organisationName>
                        <gco:CharacterString>HOUSE</gco:CharacterString>
                    </gmd:organisationName>
                </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
</gmd:pointOfContact>
</gmi:MI_Metadata>
```

and the tag "individualName" is missing

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your input XML? Also, can you also show the output you are currently getting? Thank you.

Comment: @Tim C thanks for the suggestion. I added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try

```
<xsl:template match="gmd:individualName">
   <xsl:choose>
        <!-- check if gco:CharacterString exist -->
        <xsl:when test="gco:CharacterString">    
               <xsl:text>Responsible: </xsl:text>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="gco:CharacterString"/>
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NO Responsible: ;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="gmd:individualName">
   <xsl:choose>
        <!-- check if gco:CharacterString contains text -->
        <xsl:when test="string-length(gco:CharacterString) &gt; 0">    
               <xsl:text>Responsible: </xsl:text>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="gco:CharacterString"/>
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NO Responsible: ;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @jonicleva thanks for your response but, unfortunately, it is still not working. I tested it on an xml where the responsible name is present

Comment: Hi @sylar_80, I updated the code, it is preferable to use "apply-templates" instead of "value-of", because the "value-of" does not process children, it only shows the text.
But how you have described it, also serves, I hope to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are outputting just text, you shouldn't really be trying to copy elements with `xsl:copy`, so you don't really need the template with the mode of "output". Additionally, the template that "suppresses nodes" is not needed because XSLT's built-in template will already do the same thing.

Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0"
xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts"
xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="gmd:pointOfContact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="gmd:individualName/gco:CharacterString">    
               <xsl:text>Responsible: </xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="gmd:individualName/gco:CharacterString" />
               <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NO Responsible: ;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, your suggestion works if used with my extracted example. But if applied to the entire xml I have as output the entire text contained in the .xml. :( This is why I was using the approach with the "suppress mode "  and xsl:copy

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution starting from @jonycleva suggestion:

```
<xsl:template match="gmd:pointOfContact/gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty"> <xsl:choose> 
<xsl:when test="gmd:individualName/gco:CharacterString"> <xsl:text>Responsible: </xsl:text> 
<xsl:value-of select="gmd:individualName/gco:CharacterString"/> 
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text> 
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:otherwise>Responsible: ;</xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

perhaps is not the most elegant one but it seems to work.

Any other suggestions are still welcome